# How to add more robots to stageros?

Tags: simulation, ros-hydro, simulator-stage, stage, stageros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to add another robot to this stage:

http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/SimulatingOneRobot

but I don't know how. I just found this tutorial

http://wiki.ros.org/stage/Tutorials/Creating%20Custom%20World%20in%20Stage

about how to personalize a stage in stageros but unfortunately it is incomplete.

Can someone help me in that please?

Best,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206526/how-to-add-more-robots-to-stageros?/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2015-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I answer to myself: You can add more robots editing the .world file of the stage that you are using. For example, if you are using willow-erratic it would be willow-erratic.world. This file is located at /opt/ros//share/stage_ros/world/

You need to add the following definition to the file:

erratic( pose [ -13.277 23.266 0 180.000 ] name "Quasi" color "blue")

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2015-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0